# APNS SSL Certificate & VOIP Services Certificate in parallel

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, voip

***I would like to use both VOIP Services Certificate and APNS SSL certificate in parallel for the same app.*** Will it create any issues while handling the push?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can both be used by the same application; however those pushes need to be sent on different socket connections(using different tokens) as the socket connection requires the certificate.